# Undefined value with declared values JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So here's the problematic code

```
var board = [
 {
   grdNbr: 1,
   value: 0,
 },
 {
   grdNbr: 2,
   value: 0,
 },
 { 
   grdNbr: 3,
   value: 0,
 },
 {
   grdNbr: 4,
   value: 0,
 },
 {
   grdNbr: 5,
   value: 0,
 },
 {
   grdNbr: 6,
   value: 0,
 },
 {
   grdNbr: 7,
   value: 0,
 },
 {
   grdNbr: 8,
   value: 0,
 },
 {
   grdNbr: 9,
   value: 0,
 },
]
```

I tried declaring objects as arrays, but I don't really get how it works, so please explain it to me. So, back to the topic. When I check the value it shows `undefined` (the code is below)

```
switch(board.grdNbr){

 case 1:
  board.value = 1
  console.log(board.value)
  bg.bg1 = x
  msg.channel.send(boardDRW)
  turn++
  break;
...
}
```

After that, in the console log the value for `value` is 1, but before that the value is `undefined`. Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Board is a JSONArray you need need specify the position like board[0].grdNbr

Comment: I answered the Why you get an undefined value, but if you edit your code and contextualize what you try to achieve I will update my post to help you achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I begin, I want to thank you that you spent some time helping me out. I found a solution to my problem with a different code, so I'm very sorry for wasting your time.
Have a nice day!

- Abyzls

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your board variable is an array of object, and you try to access directly a parameter of the array without specifying what object of the array you wanna access.

Instead of trying to access a value with `board.value`, you should use `board[index].value` with index being the index of the object in that list (exemple : `board[0].value`)